# Sending model from view to controller - Kendo grid

Tags: c#, kendo-grid

I have a method which return a view and a model to the view.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file){

//code shortened for brevity
ViewBag.Message = String.Format(cmdMessage);
return View("Index", three);

}
```

and I have my view, where I have a Kendo grid, like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<ModelLayer.Models.TableNotificationModel>
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Kendo.Mvc
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "UPLOAD"; }

<div class="clearfix">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelLayer.Models.TableNotificationModel>()
        .Name("notificationGrid")
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Input(true).Numeric(false))
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .ColumnMenu()

        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.OPERATOR_OBJECTID).Title("ID").Hidden();
            columns.Bound(c => c.SETTLEMENT_OBJECTID).Title("settlement code").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.TECHNOLOGY_OBJECTID).Title("tech code").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.UPLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_OBJECTID).Title("upload").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_OBJECTID).Title("download").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.DATA_CATEGORY_QOS_OBJECTID).Title("data category").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.SHAPE).Title("shape").Width("100px");
            columns.Bound(c => c.messageOut).Title("message").Width("100px");
        })
        .Excel(excel => excel
        .FileName("Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx")
        .Filterable(true)
        .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Upload")))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Upload_Read", "Upload").Data("additionalData"))
            )
    )

</div>

<script>
    function additionalData(e) {
        return {
            additional: "custom Text"
        };
    }
</script>
```

I have this js function `additionalData` but I am not sure how to send the model from the function to the method in the controller to this `Upload_read` method which will populate the Kendo grid with data.

```
public ActionResult Upload_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
 {
   DataSourceResult dataSource = result.ToDataSourceResult(request);
   return Json(dataSource.ToDataSourceResult(request));
 }
```

I am not entirely sure how to send the model. Any advice or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will come in handy to someone, here's how I made it word:

```
 function sendAdditional() {
        
        var data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))');
        console.log("index data", data)

        return {
            model: data
        }
    }
```

and the controller

```
public ActionResult Upload_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, List<TableNotificationModel> model)
        {
            return Json(dataSource.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

and I am getting the list of models in the controller from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you send the data to the server so that you can get it in the table later?
If you just need to build a table then use:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("notificationGrid")
   ...
```

If the question is in sorting, etc., then you can simply put the parameter ServerOperation(false).

Comment: I tried this and I can't even build the solution. It throws an error saying:
`The type arguments for method WidgetFactory<TableNotificationModel>.Grid<T>(IEnumerable<T>)cannot be inferred from the usage.`